# Any way to access web part controls/HTML content for a publishing page in server-side code

Tags: page-layout, publishing-page, user-controls, design-manager

I'm in a situation where I want to grab the web part controls and/or HTML content of the controls for a publishing page, and format the content before it is rendered.

How can I go about this? I've thought about using a UserControl to run server-side code, or perhaps in the layout that the content resides in? However, the layout is in the design manager.

How can I access this published page content before it is rendered?

**Edit**: The end goal is to allow users to specify HTML tags (i.e. *data-* attributes) and handle them on the server-side to hide and display content based on varying business scenarios; thus, allowing them to easily add/edit content that will be displayed dynamically).

*SharePoint 2013 - On premise*

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Page.Controls` for getting the control in Server Side.

From your update I think below approach will work

1. Create a Custom List to capture fields to Hide
2. Now using Browser Tool find the element id and store it in the configuration list
3. Now you need to take a decision whether to user Client Side or Serve Side
4. If client side - Then use a Script Editor Webpart and user JavaScript to read custom configuration list and use jQuery to hide elements
5. If server side - Then create a new webpart and read configuration list and iterate through Page Controls and remove or hide elements.